# How can i get the title of top selling games on steam using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I am trying to make a dataset which requires me get titles of steam top selling games in python

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r"{binary_location}"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"{driver_location}", options=options)

driver.get("https://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=topsellers")

titles = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='title']").text
titles
```

This only outputs the first title which is

```
Counter-Strike: Global Offensive
```

I need all the titles of the games which are present on the web page

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sLBe.png)

**please don't suggest using beautifulsoup i specifically need using selenium in python**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for multiple elements:

```
titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='title']")

titles = [title.text for title in titles]
```

Comment: .text doesn't work by yeah I got it

Comment: @VishalPadia I fixed the post. If my answer was correct and helped you, please mark it with the check mark :)

Comment: Did that but I still have one question:
it is still returning only the first 50 elements what should I do to get all??

Comment: I think the website is using pagination. Try to figure out how to scroll down using Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `find_elements` instead of `find_element`:

```
titles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='title']")
```

Then, using for loop you can get the text of each webelement:

```
for title in titles:
    print(title.text)
```